# Haxe documentation XML: how to exclude standard library?

Tags: xml, documentation, haxe, documentation-generation, rtti

I want to make a small tool in Haxe, that inspects the haxedoc comments. I figured the best way to get these comments is to use the "haxe -xml" option, and load in the resulting XML file.

However, when I generate the XML, it seems to include the whole standard library in the output XML. When I pass this XML in to Dox, it generates documentation for my code *and* the standard library stuff, e.g. Class, Date, String, Enum...

Is this expected behaviour? Is there some way to exclude the standard library entries from the generated XML? Or should I write my tool to filter the XML based on package/filename/etc?

Here is my build script:

#### /build.hxml

```
-cp src
-neko main.n
--no-output
-xml bin/xml/neko.xml
--macro "include('doctest')"
```

Here's the file I want to generate XML for:

#### /src/doctest/Main.hx

```
package doctest;

//import neko.Lib;

/**
 * ...
 * @author jjokin
 */
class Main 
{
    static function main() 
    {
    }
}

/**
 * This class does some stuff.
 */
class DemoClass {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I think I've worked it out. The compiled XML must always include everything - such as Array, Enum, Class, List - since these are needed for compilation to other languages. I've had a look at Dox, and it has the options "-in/--include", and "-ex/--exclude", which lets you filter the elements to produce documentation for. So, my module will need to do something similar.

Comment: You could possibly also play with calling `Compiler.exclude("String")` etc, to exclude them from being generated. I haven't tested if this works on Xml documentation, but it's maybe worth a shot. Filtering the complete list is what most libraries seem to do though. See http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/Compiler.html#exclude

Comment: For anyone returning here in the future, using `haxelib run dox -in "^your\.package\.regex" …` works properly – only includes your classes, not the stdlib. `-ex` is not needed.